# Общий контроллер в Yii2

Tags: yii2, фреймворк

Смотрю уроки по данному фреймворку. Возникла проблема на общем контроллере. Делал всё как на видео - не работает.

```
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=9_zvtBEUn_0&list=PL9XdPIVgBVVmYWGF3BFZwHu4Fz9fa6GJd&index=5
```

В папке controllers создал файл AppController с таким кодом:

```
<?php
namespace app\controllers;
use yii;
use yii\web\Controller;

class AppController extends Controller
{
    function r($arr)
    {
        echo '<pre>' . print_r($arr, true) . '</pre>';
    }
}
function debug($arr){
    echo '<pre>' . print_r($arr, true) . '</pre>';
}
```

Функция debug должна быть доступна везде.
Создал файл test.php в папке views.
Вызываю метод debug:

```
\app\controllers\debug(Yii::$app);
```

Получаю ошибку:

```
Call to undefined function app\controller\debug() in C:\OSPanel\domains\localhost\basic\views\post\test.php on line 2
```

Вот путь к контроллеру и виду:

```
C:\OSPanel\domains\localhost\basic\controllers\AppController.php
C:\OSPanel\domains\localhost\basic\views\post\test.php
```

Помогите разобраться, ибо это мой первый фреймворк и очень туго воспринимается.
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: `Функция debug должна быть доступна везде` - почему? Она у вас даже в классе не находится. Скорее всего проблема именно в этом.

Comment: Ну в видео было указано, что функцию нужно оформить за пределами класса. Потому так и сделал.

Comment: Только что пересмотрел. Там 2 скобки открылось, 2 закрылось. И дальше идёт уже общая функция. Прикрепил скрин к вопросу

Comment: Это выглядит странно, но ок........ тогда проблема в том что ты не так пишешь.... потому что в ошибке `controller` написан без `s` на конце. Значит ты пишешь без неё... а также `app`  без обратного слеша...

Comment: Но внешнюю функцию никто не делает - это глупо. К тому же в yii2 есть свой debug и можно пользоваться им... А если и пользоваться своим написанным выводом - то явно не так

Comment: Это чисто пример как делать внешнюю функцию

Comment: Слэш убрал, вернул, поставил обратный - вообще ничего.

Comment: Покажи код в твоем `view`

Comment: <?
app\controllers\debug(Yii::$app);

Comment: `<?php \app\controllers\debug(Yii::$app); ?>`  - где *php* потерял и обратный слеш?

Comment: Давайте [продолжим обсуждение в чате](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/66839/discussion-between--and--).

Answer (score 1):

Функции имеют вид: `function public`, `protected` и `private + static`. Здесь `function debug` вывалилась из класса, исправь. Вместо `echo` надо поставить `return`. Также, если будет `static`, то должно вызваться так:

```
путь\к\модели::getФункции(),
```

Если же ты передавал модель, то так:

```
модель->функция
```

Comment: Спасибо за ответ, но я уже ушёл чуть дальше)

Comment: ага, пока набирал увидел что уже почти как пол года не актуально, но жалко было удалять ответ) Успехов!